# Resource request on use of comma

Tags: discussion, resources

May I request (I think I may?) an exhaustive resource on the use of commas in the English language, for someone whose first language is English. A book resource would be fine, especially if it covers other issues in a canonical way.

Comment: Style manuals, [Chicago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style) or [MLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MLA_Handbook), I guess are your best bets, they are the ones I hear most often nominated onEL&U,  that or any book that covers punctuation.

Comment: Online resource: [the punctuation guide](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/comma.html) or just [Google](https://www.google.com/search?ei=8kwRWqXUDYnaUqLovKAB&q=punctuation+comma+usage+&oq=punctuation+comma+usage+&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0i22i30k1l2.25523.31013.0.35230.11.10.1.0.0.0.196.1495.0j10.10.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.11.1516...33i22i29i30k1j33i160k1.0.AEM41z-Q5qA)

Comment: Oxford Manual of Style for BrE, Chicago Manual of Style for AmE.

Comment: Since you have asked, strictly speaking, I do not think it is permitted here, and [I have explained why before](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10641/124936). I would advise asking on the [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) website instead, where [resource requests](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request) are expressly permitted by [the scope of their website](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). With that having been said though, nobody actually seems to like or enforce that particular policy.

Comment: thanks to all three of you. :)

Comment: @Tonepoet SE's policy is a general guide. Each community enforces its own subset of policies. We often write answers in comments, for example. See also: [Individual community preferences vs. SE network policy: who wins?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124915/309993)

Comment: See also: “[What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573/14073)” from our FAQ series.