# Meta and Reference Sources: The Invisible Man?

Tags: discussion

ELU Meta contains questions that exist as resources for (generally) less knowledgable users. In principle I think this is a good thing as it keeps questions about reference sources (rather than English) off the main site, as well as being valuable in itself. Indeed my post is motivated by the idea of introducing an analogous resource on my own ‘home’ site of SE Biology.

But…

> How are users expected to find these resources, or even know that
> they are there?

I am an experienced user and internet searcher, so I searched for dictionaries and found this useful question/answer:
[What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available)

However, I don’t know if there are any other such Q/As hidden away, and they would seem to me almost useless if they are not advertised to posters. Are they, and I’m just missing something as I don’t ask many questions myself? If not, is there any way they could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On questions that are closed with the below-mentioned banner, the phrase "commonly-available references" is a direct link to ELU meta's "What good reference works on English are available?"

> Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using **commonly-available references** are off-topic.

In addition, you may find more information by following the meta tag [resources](/questions/tagged/resources).

Ideally, all useful resources from individual questions should be curated/compiled under the same Q&A "What good reference works on English are available?" so that it's easy to be found.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I hadn't noticed there was a link incorporated into the close notice. It may be advice after the event, but problem posters ignore any advice before the event in any case. Pity the SE format doe not allow custom page layout so that one could include it in one of the side columns.

Comment: @David See also: A brief note on _why_ we have [allowed resource requests on meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10584/50044)