# Why is my reputation getting smaller?

Tags: bug, reputation

So I recently started to post questions on ELU. No prob there. Anyways, when I reached about 95 reputation, it started to shrink for some reason until it was about 83.

I ignored it, as usual, and everything went back to normal.

I was on a vacation, so I couldn’t go on ELU. After the vacation, I returned home, and saw that 6 reputation has been remouved.

I went to my profile, but it didn’t say anything about me getting downvotes.

Is it because my flags was declined for some questions, I wasn’t active or is it automatic when you reach about 90 reputation?

So why is my reputation shrinking?

Comment: How much did you lose exactly? You claim you _had_ 95 before the shrinking. I see 93 now. Please check you reputation history here: https://english.stackexchange.com/users/261298/?tab=reputation

Comment: I think I had 98 rep. Now I have 93. @NVZ

Comment: You have several accounts, but it's still worth mentioning that votes on Meta.ELU (and other Meta sites, with the exception of Meta.stackexchange itself) don't count towards reputation. Also, at some point, you will get an association bonus of 100 on your accounts, if you keep gaining rep.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no automatic rep loss when you reach a certain rep. There is no rep loss when you get flags declined.

You did receive 2 downvotes today (23/1/18) as seen on [your reputation history](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/261298/?tab=reputation). Perhaps that's what you're referring to.

Downvotes, if there are many on a post, is usually a sign that there is something odd about the post - and in this case, it's an off-topic question that showed poor [research effort](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5043/50044).

> I searched the dictionary but it didn’t give me clear answers. I know it has something to do with medicine and drugs.

You could have mentioned what dictionary you referred to, what definition you found, and how that is not helping you understand the word in question.

And keep participating, and only then will you fully grasp the concept of what's on-topic and what's not. It takes a while for everyone.

Comment: Very nice answer. Clear and direct. Thank you for your continued contributions to meta. I know it must sometimes feel a chore that no one is is throwing a hand in to help you with, and yet you persevere. Just wanted you to know we see it, and are grateful.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks. I actually like meta better than main. On main, I've got limits on what I can answer. I, being not a native speaker or an expert, do not know how to answer questions there. And I'm actually tired of answering SWRs. So meta it is... :)