# Commonly-available reference issue

Tags: discussion, support, general-reference

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/129681/jel) user  posted this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460613/is-there-any-adjectival-form-of-audit/469231#469231) in October 2018.

I have an issue with the link they have provided.

The user has provided a definition from the OED and a link that takes you to the [OED's homepage.](http://oed.com)

The problem is, you have to pay £/$90 or 7.50/month to *access* the OED's definitions.  I raised this issue in the comments, stating it wasn't a commonly-available reference since it's paywalled.

Apparently, the user thinks that the OED *is* a commonly-available reference, mentioning that s/he could find "7.50 a month down the back of my sofa" etc.  I then informed him/her that this is an unnecessary addition that could be considered offensive by some.

**Then** they call me out for 'trolling' and subsequently delete their comments, but the chat transcript can be found [here.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/91184)

- #### Is it right to call the OED a commonly-available reference?
- #### Was I wrong to call this out?
- #### They could've easily linked the **free** Merriam-Webster instead.
- **This is what I feel is wrong:**
   1) They have quoted the OED and linked the **homepage** (?)
   2) They picked the OED over Merriam-Webster (easily-accessible)
   3) After I mention this, they edit the question **but** deliberately ignore my suggestion and leave the OED homepage sitting there.

(FWIW, I do have access to the OED)

Comment: @Mitch Is the OED home the correct link to use?  This does seem to exclude a lot of people globally.  And should I expect this comment-realise-delete andbehaviour from a 30k'er?

Comment: Oh. Just the home page of OED? Uh... sure, it shows the source (which is just a general life skill so that you aren't plagiarizing. It doesn't really help with reducing clicks, like a direct link. But it's fine. Re: comment deleting, I can't say. I don't think they were covering up bad behavior, they probably thought it wasn't relevant anymore.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your issue with the answer (perhaps in part because it’s been edited and comments have been deleted). The OED is definitely not a commonly-available resource, but sources in answers don’t have to be commonly-available resources. We expect _askers_ to look in CRs before posting, and questions that can be answered by doing so alone are off-topic; but that doesn’t mean _answers_ are limited to them. It’s common enough to link to a paywalled source and simply add “(paywalled)” after the link.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I haven't mentioned this, but they could've *easily* linked  Merriam-Webster instead.  This is my problem.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet This is what I feel is wrong:  1) They have quoted the OED and linked the **homepage** (?) 2)  They picked the OED over Merriam-Webster (easily-accessible) 3)  After I mention this, they edit the question **but** deliberately ignore my suggestion and leave the OED homepage sitting there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OED is paywalled, but many people in the US and UK can get access to the OED for free through their local public libraries. This unfortunately leaves out quite a few people of the world. However it is a strong ELU guideline that if something like the OED is used or likewise any free on-line services, that **both a quote *and* a link is given**.

I can't say you're wrong to point out that the OED is paywalled but that's more a complaint to OED, not to the OP.

It's a hard call. The OED is the absolute best reference for multiple entries, obscurities, etymology, subtleties. pretty much all the others are missing something or don't provide the detail that OED does.

My recommendation is if you can't get a link somehow to the OED (I do through my local public library; I have to jump through some hoops (clicking a bunch of times, hoping I typed in my library ID number correctly), but it's worth the few moments of trouble), you should google for the definition **and read *all* the definitions**. Assuming the first definition that proves your first point is walking a wobbly tightrope.

Comment: Did I mention not all dictionaries have the same definitions?

Comment: @Lordology, if all dictionaries had exactly the same definitions, there would be only one dictionary and English would be a *lot* less nuanced (probably)! Language isn't static, and they all update differently, too. OED is often looked on as the authority among dictionaries, and a very good source, even if it is paywalled. FWIW, I would have provided the Merriam-Webster link and definition in a comment if I thought it would add to the answer (or suggested an edit).

Comment: @Pam Also, there are fallible people writing these things. There's no guarantee that someone would write the same definition from one day to the next, even with both correct.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see a problem with quoting from non-free resources if all the rules are followed. Specifically, we require answers provide enough content in the answer that it doesn't matter if the link works, to prevent link rot. It's not even required to link to the source as long as the source is named and there's enough information to find it (after all, we do allow people to quote dead trees—aka books). In any case, the linked answer is following the rules.

Sometimes a paywalled source is just better than what’s available freely. If not, there's also nothing wrong with suggesting another source for an answer but you shouldn't get into an argument. One comment should be enough.

Fun fact: Even if you do link to the OED, the link will not even work for everyone who has access. This is because some institutions have their own URL scheme where instead of OED.com, it’s something like oed-com.myorg.org. (This is why I only link to publicly available OED pages.)

---

It's also worth mentioning that on ELU "commonly-available reference" has a specific meaning used in this close reason:

> Please **include the [research](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5039)** you've done, or consider if your question suits our [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2573) are off-topic.

While the "commonly-available references" link lists the OED, I would not consider it one because it is not freely available. Questions should not be closed simply because the OED has the answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention this, but they could've easily linked Merriam-Webster instead. This is my problem. You may want to consider editing. (up to you)