# Please help me improve my question on 'dishonest mistake' (re the term 'honest mistake')

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, editing, specific-question

The question: *[There's the term 'honest mistake', so what is 'dishonest mistake' synonymous to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/578934/theres-the-term-honest-mistake-so-dishonest-mistake-is-synonymous-to)*

I am not really sure I have anything to say in the body besides the link except that the question was closed and probably deservedly.

Comment: What do you mean by "[re](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/re#Preposition)" (the title)? In that context.

Comment: @PeterMortensen it's been modified already (by you! thanks again!) but 're' is like regards or relation or respect right? (but for respect i guess i should say with respect instead of in respect) wait yeah in your link. reference/regard

Comment: The commentary is giving feedback as to why the OP is struggling to improve/fix their question, which I believe is relevant.

Comment: Just went to read the question expecting to see a single paragraph or little more. Instead the question has a significant number of reflections and considerations, perhaps even too many.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks for both honesty and empathy i guess!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To improve your question,

- arrange your thoughts in a logical order;
- make it easy to follow and **concise;**
- do **not** address individual comments either in comments or identifiably in the question: edit your question to take them into account and then flag the comment as "no longer required". Editing your question could involve a complete re-write, depending on what the comment says and how that affects your logical order. Once you complete an edit, your question should **look** as though it's just been asked, without "Edit" headers, addenda or afterthoughts. [However, don't invalidate existing answers! There could be a fine line to tread.]

It's not **entirely** applicable here, but you might want to have a look at my answer about [research](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5043/18696) because it is tangentially relevant.

Comment: The concise part is supposed to be in the question at the very start and the division into sections and subsections and stuff. This way even if the whole thing is long, people can just skip the parts they don't like. It's like a textbook: you don't necessarily read the whole thing. anyway thanks Andrew Leach edited further and now submitting for review

Comment: clear now but now opinion-based? https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15185/was-my-question-closed-for-lacking-clarity-and-then-became-clear-but-remained-cl